# IIS site within virtual directory Swagger UI end point

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

Swagger UI end point is not same as dev in staging ( excluding domain names)

IIS Configuration

[image]

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)

 app.UseSwagger(c=>
        {
            //Change the path of the end point , should also update UI middle ware for this change                
            c.RouteTemplate = "api-docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";                 
        });          

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {  
            //Include virtual directory if site is configured so
            c.SwaggerEndpoint(Configuration["Appsettings:VirtualDirectory"]+"api-docs/v1/swagger.json", "Api v1");                
        });

 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
 var xmlDocPath = Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath, "Api.xml");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlDocPath);
            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
```

with the above configuration

Development

```
 "AppSettings": {
"VirtualDirectory": "/"
```

}

Staging

```
 "AppSettings": {
"VirtualDirectory": "/Api/"
```

}

The end point for UI on the dev machine with staging ON

```
http://localhost:5001/api-docs/v1/swagger.json
```

but the same one on the staging server

```
http://xxxx:5002/swagger/Api/api-docs/v1/swagger.json
```

instead of ( what it should be)

```
http://xxxx:5002/Api/api-docs/v1/swagger.json
```

Comment: show how you set the env as Staging on dev machine, as right now it looks like you did it wrong. Did you set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable to `Staging` or what you used?

Comment: exactly, ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is more relevant to swagger than Environment variable. Swagger does support the virtual directory which then the configuration should look like below. Note that virtual directory doesn't affect the UI End point.

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                //Change the path of the end point , should also update UI middle ware for this change                
                c.RouteTemplate = "api-docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";
            });
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                //Include virtual directory if site is configured so
                c.RoutePrefix = "api-docs";
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "Api v1");
            });
```

Answer (score 11):

Adding "../" works for websites hosted under virtual directory and without virtual directory

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TestService");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed this line in Swagger UI configure (Startup.cs):

```
c.SwaggerEndpoint("/prueba/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Swagger (....)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, None of them works for me.
I have tried all of them.

Working solution:

```
app.UseSwagger(c => {
    c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is,

```
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyDevOpsAPI V1");
        });
```

Note that I have removed the leading "/".

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to get it running so i want to share my solution here

```
    string vpath = s.GetValue<string>("VirtualPath") ?? string.Empty;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vpath))
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", endpointName); });
    }
    else
    {
            app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                //no virtual path in the roue template it is relative 
                c.RouteTemplate = $"swagger/{{documentName}}/swagger.json";
                //c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, request) => swagger.BasePath = $"/{vpath}");
            });
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                //options.RoutePrefix = vpath;
                //gives the location of the gennerated json file to the UI
                //start with / to create an absolute path from the base directory
                options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/{vpath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", endpointName);
            });
    }
```

Comment: s.GetValue, who is s ?

Comment: @LeresAldtai the configuration section. I later ended up using NSwag which has no more problems with virtual directories