# Swagger is not generating swagger.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-2.1

I have the asp.net core MVC project and separate WebApi project in one solution. I'm adding the swagger following the documentation on github. Here is my Startup.cs of mvc project:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...
        // Adding controllers from WebApi:
        var controllerAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("WebApi"));
        services.AddMvc(o =>
            {
                o.Filters.Add<GlobalExceptionFilter>();
                o.Filters.Add<GlobalLoggingFilter>();
            })
            .AddApplicationPart(controllerAssembly)
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            //The generated Swagger JSON file will have these properties.
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Title = "Swagger XML Api Demo",
                Version = "v1",
            });
        });

        //...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //...
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Swagger XML Api Demo v1");
        });

        //...

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            // ...
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Here are the nugets:

[image: nugets]

The WebApi controllers Attribute routing:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    // ...
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return Ok(await _repo.GetCategoriesEagerAsync());
    }
    // ...
}
```

When I'm trying to go to /swagger it doesn't find the /swagger/v1/swagger.json:
[image: Json not found]

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the output folder to see if the `json` file is actually present?

Comment: And are you using Kestrel or other webserver (iisexpress). And the commented parts in the `Configure` do not contain an if dev-env something? and you have a release build which will never hit it like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450262/asp-net-core-swashbuckle-not-creating-swagger-json-file

Comment: @JamieRees, yes, I've searched for the json. It's not there in the project folders.

Comment: If you put `.UseMvc()`  before Swagger, does it work? The order in my code is ) MVC 2) Swagger, but I don't know if there was a reason for that :)

Comment: @JPHellemons, I've tried with IIS Express and IIS, no environment specific code

Comment: @John I've tried both: and before .UseMvc() and after. The same result.

Comment: Other than that, your code is the same as mine. I'm afraid i have no suggestions.

Comment: In my experience, this has had to do with the URL you're serving the API from, if it's served from the root or not, and how the absolute `/swagger/v1/swagger.json` is resolved based on that. Try a relative `swagger/v1/swagger.json` for example and see if you can hit it directly from your browser.

Comment: Was your project migrated to .net core 2.1?

Comment: @SaebAmini I've already tried to reach the json directly: http://localhost/aspnet_core_2018Q3/swagger/swagger/v1/swagger.json . The result is the same. Also it seems the swagger middleware is getting called only when I go to /swagger page

Comment: @JPHellemons yes. But it was not working on 2.0 as well

Comment: Do you have `<PreserveCompilationContext>false</PreserveCompilationContext>` into the .csproj file? If so, remove it.

Comment: @NikitaFedorov have you tried `c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json"` instead of `c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json"`?

Comment: @JPHellemons no, I haven't

Comment: @SaebAmini yeas, I've tried both

Comment: It should generate even empty document if it has some trouble to find any API methods right?

Comment: Try this one answer, I have find out helpful for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64646362/7404931

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on this problem for hours... and I found the reason...

Check the code below !!

..**Startup.cs**..

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseSwagger(); // if I remove this line, do not work !
    app.UseSwaggerUi3();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add my experience here as well.
I have given the version in `configureServices` as `V1` (notice the `V` in caps) and

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", //this v was in caps earlier
            new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info
            {
                Version = "v1",//this v was in caps earlier
                Title = "Tiny Blog API",
                Description = "A simple and easy blog which anyone love to blog."
            });
        });
        //Other statements
    }
```

And then in the `configure` method it was in small case

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Tiny Blog V1");
        });
    }
```

May be it can help someone.

Comment: How to export swagger.json to the local physical location?

Comment: Just use the endpoint. example for me the location is `https://localurl/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you set environment correctly, and is the command `app.UseSwagger` isn't inside a if to execute only on a determined environment like development.

A test solution is to add the line `app.UseSwagger(`) outside any conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code using .net core 6:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(s =>
{
    s.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Service Manager API", Description = "API Docs for the Service Manager Layer.", Version = "v1"});
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Service Manager API V1");
});

app.Run();
```

I ran into the problem simply by not adding "/" to the Path (/swagger/v1... not swagger/v1/...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more reason, if you are missing adding [HttpGet(Name = "")] attributed on top of your action method.

If this help to anyone.