# How to fix swagger.json not found in .net core 2.2 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm deploying my .net core app on IIS server and facing the issue in swagger UI where swagger.json not found. When I run it locally (Development environment) everything is working perfectly but when I deploy it on IIS server it fails to find swagger.json file.

Previously I was facing this issue in .net core 2.1 app and I resolved it by writing below code to get the virtual base path.

```
string basePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH");
            basePath = basePath == null ? "/" : (basePath.EndsWith("/") ? basePath : $"{basePath}/");

 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
     {
      c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{basePath}swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test.Web.Api");
      c.RoutePrefix = "";
     });
```

I have tried below code to resolve it:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
   app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
     {
      c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{env.ContentRootPath}swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test.Web.Api");
       //OR
      c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{env.WebRootPath}swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test.Web.Api");
      c.RoutePrefix = "";
     });
 }
```

But abouve code didn't worked as it returns actual physical path and not virtual path.

- **An output of the above code**: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/myapp/swagger/v1/swagger.json
- **Expected output**: http://myserver/MySite/swagger/v1/swagger.json

Does anyone know how to get the virtual path in .net core 2.2 as `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH");` is not working. Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: According to the Swashbuckle docs, you should be able to just use "./swagger/v1/swagger.json" and not prepend the hosting URL.  Did that not work? Edited to add period to front of path because I noticed this was not running at the root of the domain.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too but didn't work. Failed to fetch the swagger.json file.

Comment: I had similar issue but the reason may be different. if anyone want can view my experience [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162321/swagger-is-not-generating-swagger-json/57369669#57369669)

Answer (score 15):

I have fixed my issue by putting below code in my .net core app.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
   app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
     {
      c.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test.Web.Api");
      c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
 }
```

As per [swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) documentation you need to prepend the ./ if you are hosting it in IIS.

I hope this answer will save your time!

Comment: Yup, but I missed "." before "/". Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. I have application hosted using IIS express and had set `launchsettings.json` as `"iisExpress": { "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/char",` to test IIS virtual directory. However the problem is that `localhost/char/swagger` shows 404 error but `localhost/char/swagger/v1/swagger.json` works (the json file is shown). `localhost/swagger` works fine if there is no path in the `applicationUrl` value. I'm using `netcore31` and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0` package

Comment: @VAAA yes I did. Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60170381/940182) in this thread

Comment: This solution saved my life!

Answer (score 6):

I've tried to use `c.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test.Web.Api");` from the [Mahesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54407878/940182) but the problem is that it does not help.

I've got [Swashbuckle sample](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger/samples/3.0) started from VS using IIS Express

I'm getting error

> Failed to load API definition. undefined ./swagger/v1/swagger.json

when was accessing the `localhost/char/swagger` endpoint from the web browser.

I had modified `launchsettings.json\iisExpress\applicationUrl` and added the path like `"iisExpress": { "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/char"`
and `Startup.cs` source code like

```
   app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
     {
      c.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test.Web.Api");
      c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
```

The solution was found at the [Github issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/971#issuecomment-402338886) please find it below:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API");
});
```

I have not seen it in the documentation but it is working when

- hosted by IIS Express locally with (or without) additional path after host name in the `iisExpress\applicationUrl`
- hosted by IIS on staging environment (with additional path after hostname like `http://staginghost/char/swagger`

Comment: @GabrielSimas this solution is two years old. Try to post new Swashbuckle.WebApi issue it you beleive that did it properly.

Answer (score 6):

For .net core 5, swagger is added automatically on project creating.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyProject.Api", Version = "v1" });
    });
}
```

However, you need to make sure that two commented lines are out of the if block.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider svp)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                //app.UseSwagger();
                //app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyProject.Api v1"));
            }

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyProject.Api v1"));                 

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

i have faced this issue and found that you have to match the exact typing of Version in the path and both servicescollection and appbuilder

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1" , new OpenApiInfo{ Title = "MyApp API" , Version = "v1" });
 });

 app.UseSwagger(); app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { 
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json","MyApp API v1"); });
```

Answer (score 2):

In my cases I forgot to add HTTPGet Attribute one of my controller public get method

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the same in the following way:

Package: #region Assembly Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Version=4.0.1.0

Framework: .Net Core 2.2

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwagger();
    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
    // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
         c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Versioned Api v1");
    );
}
```

This is work when you run the application locally or hosted on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

For .Net Core 2.2

```
  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerDocument();
```

then

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseOpenApi();
            app.UseSwaggerUi3();

        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.