# Swagger ui is not disposing of deleted controllers can still few but dont work

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

My swagger is not updating the end points I deleted the controller but yet the case items are still showing on the swagger end point. The cases end point

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Warehouse Crm", Version = "v1" });
            //   c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
            //Expose XML comments in doc.
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Description =
                    "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer"
            });
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        },
                        Scheme = "oauth2",
                        Name = "Bearer",
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                }
            });
        });
```

The bit in blue has been deleted from the controllers so should not be there. The solution has been built and cleaned so no idea as to why its still showing in the ui

[image]

As you see here

[image]

**Edit 3**

My Configure section showing that I am using   app.UseSwagger();

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        } else {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();
     
        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1"); });
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                "default",
                "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: clean the temporary files, also bin and obj folders

Comment: Where is it happening? On dev machine or in staging/production?

Comment: only on the dev machine i dont have the other systems up yet the product is not finished @user2250152

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu as mentioned i cleaned the project

Comment: cleaning the project does not delete the temp files, they will be on C windows temp aspnet folder, something like that

Comment: and a sideways comment, you don't need the Delete verb in the URL, just as you don't have PostCases or GetCases

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu im removing the entire cases verb but of course thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu i cleaned out the temp files and its still their its almost like its not refreshing the swager.json file or regen it

Comment: Are you using `app.UseSwagger();` in Configure method? I think its because of this.

Comment: Check this question and see if any of the answers help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450262/asp-net-core-swashbuckle-not-creating-swagger-json-file

Comment: @1.44mb yes I am please see my config section in edit 3 above thanks

Comment: You have the comment `//Expose XML comments in doc.` but no where the xml doc is loaded, do you have masked some lines?

Comment: (And don't use IE, too many problem to use Swagger UI)

Comment: @Vernou who said I use ie i use google chrome for any testing !