# ASP.NET Core Web API Swagger Error - Parser error on line 13 end of the stream or a document separator is expected

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

In my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, when I launch it locally, it works. But when I deployed it to IIS, then I decided to launch it on Swagger.

I got this error:

> Parser error on line 13
> end of the stream or a document separator is expected

NB: There's nothing line 13 of my `Program.cs`

How do I resolve this?

Program.cs:

```
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using Serilog;
using System.Reflection;
using MyApp.API.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
var environment = builder.Environment;

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(op => op.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
            = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddFluentValidation(options =>
    {
        options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    });

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
// Swagger
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
// Register Dependency Injection Service Extension
builder.Services.AddDependencyInjection();

// Add services to the container
var _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(_logger);

builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My-APP API");
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Do you have any concerns about trhis issue ? If you need further help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This error message tells us that the Swagger JSON file format is incorrect, such as missing commas, parentheses mismatch, incorrect property names, and so on.

We can view the JSON file from `https://site_name/swagger/v1/swagger.json` and use the tool to see if it is complete.

We usually use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` NuGet package, which can automatically generate Swagger documents and avoid errors when manually writing Swagger JSON files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and in my case, the error is due to an incorrect swagger.json path.
I changed it to

c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My-APP API");

and it worked.

More details here: [ASP.NET Core - Swashbuckle not creating swagger.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450262/asp-net-core-swashbuckle-not-creating-swagger-json-file)