# ASP.NET Core with Swagger: 404 Response for swagger.json without any errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

Getting the common "response status is 404 https://localhost:7247/swagger/v1/swagger.json" error on my Swagger page.

If I manually open up and visit the page I don't get any ASP.NET errors, I just get a 404 response as well.

Most examples of this issue have errors that show up in the console that can be resolved to fix the lack of `swagger.json` being generated.

In my case, no errors are displayed in the terminal when I run my ASP.NET Core application.

Running with .NET 7.0, most of my nuget packages are version 7.0.12

I only have 2 controllers defined, and disabling both of them via Compile Settings does not resolve this issue, so I don't believe it's a controller route misconfiguration causing the issue.

My `Program.cs` is as follows:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    var config = EnsureConfig(builder);
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<NotesDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseNpgsql(config.Database.ConnectionString);
    });

    EnsureIdentity(builder, config);

    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        EnsureSwagger(builder); //Breakpoint here does get hit
    }

    builder.Services.AddBusinessServices();

    var app = builder.Build();

    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var dbInitService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDatabaseInitService>();
        await dbInitService.InitAsync();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();  //Breakpoint here does get hit
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.MapControllers();
    app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

    await app.RunAsync();
}

private static NotesConfig EnsureConfig(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var config = builder.Configuration.Get<NotesConfig>() ??
                 throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(
                     "Invalid Configuration, please validate configuration integrity"
                 );
    config.Validate();

    builder.Services.AddSingleton(config);
    return config;
}

private static void EnsureSwagger(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("Notes", new()
        {
            Description = "Open API Docs for Notes v1",
            Title = "Notes",
            Version = "v1",
            Contact = new()
            {
                Email = "steffen@technically.fun",
                Name = "Steffen Blake",
                Url = new Uri("https://technically.fun"),
            }
        });
        options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new()
        {
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Description = "Please insert JWT with Bearer into field",
            BearerFormat = "Bearer <token>",
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
        });
        options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    }
                },
                // scopes
                new string[] { }
            }
        });
    });
}

private static void EnsureIdentity(WebApplicationBuilder builder, NotesConfig config)
{
    builder.Services
        .AddDefaultIdentity<NotesUser>(options =>
        {
            options.Lockout = config.Identity.Lockout;
            options.Password = config.Identity.Password;
            options.SignIn = config.Identity.SignIn;
            options.User = config.Identity.User;
        })
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<NotesDbContext>();

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config.Signing.JWTSecret);
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = NotesConstants.JWT_ISSUER,
                ValidAudience = NotesConstants.JWT_ISSUER,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
            };
        });
}
```

I'm guessing it's one of those "You declared the registrations on your services or application in slightly the wrong order so it silently failed" scenarios, so I have been flipping the order of declarations around to see if it remedies the situation but no dice so far.

It may also be possible that some part of my swagger configuration is
wrong and, I guess, causing it to silently fail?

Answer (score 0):

Found the specific case, it was the same as this comment here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53521371/7839602

Fixed Swagger gen section was adding this:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/Notes/swagger.json", "Notes");
    });
}
```

The important part is the first param in `options.SwaggerDoc(...)` has to be the same as `options.SwaggerEndpoint(...)`'s second url fragment.

In my case it was `Notes` as an example