# AspNetCore Swagger/Swashbuckle and Virtual Directories

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm struggling with getting the configuration for Swagger/Swashbuckle correct in an Asp.Net core 2.0 web api.  I've followed the examples, which all work brilliantly when working at the root folder/localhost.  As many others have pointed out, I too am seeing different behavior when working in a virtual folder on the server.  I've examined this question -  [IIS site within virtual directory Swagger UI end point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45227986/97879) which is similar, but the solution provided there is not working.

My startup.cs file has the following block for configuring services:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\EmployeeService.xml", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "Employee Service"
            });
        });
...
}
```

And my Configure method looks like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Employee Service API");
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

I've tried this with and without adding the RoutePrefix to the SwaggerUI section.

As I mentioned, I'm running .Net Core 2.0.3, I have the Nuget package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 2.3.0 referenced.

What I get in the app regardless of what I do with the path is a 404 on the /swagger/v1/swagger.json file when I try to access {server}/{virtualdirectory}/swagger.  The UI loads, but it won't load the json file, as it always tries to find it at server root.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You must check your [http] route , dont use [routes] before http`s tag.

you must add a api route on the top and remove all routes before them Http:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class asteriskAPI:Controller
{ ........

}
```

and like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<ast_cel>> GetAll()
    {
  ...
   }
```

Comment: and use the last version of swagger dll

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your app.UseSwaggerUI method to this

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Employee Service API");
        });
```

Note the period.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/aspnet/aspnetcore.docs/getstarted-swashbuckle-aspnetcore/